# “What it does it does” ?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

[19:17](https://youtu.be/2Lz0VOltZKA)

> - “And so the rule **what it does it does** something really remarkable when you count backwards five four three...”

I want to know why the two words are repeated instead of saying the words this way:

> - And the rule What it does is something really remarkable.

Is it kind of emphasis on the importance of what she is going to say? Or is a kind of questioning, then she answers?

Comment: And so **the rule does what it does**. Not: the rule what it does it does. That is incorrect grammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does what it does.

**what it does** is a noun phrase, object of **does**.

With the order of the constituents reversed:

> What it does it does.

It acts how it acts.

How it acts it acts.

They spend what they spend.

What they spend they spend.

This kind of tautology suggests that there's no changing the thing. It will do what it does.  They will spend what they spend.

They want what they want.

What they want they want.

There's no bargaining with them. They're firm in what they want.

Or perhaps

People have their desires. There's no use pretending otherwise.

Comment: As a footnote, I'd put commas in a lot of these: _What it does, it does. What they spend, they spend._